# UITabBarItem in Xcode app has fatal error because found nil while implicitly unwrapping optional value. Not sure what's going wrong/ how to fix

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

*Edit: Not sure if I can mark a question as solved but it was thanks to Alex. It was an issue with the newest version of Xcode but instructions meant for an older one. Moving the code fragments from AppDelegate to SceneDelegate fixed it.*

I'm very new to Xcode and IOS app development. I'm taking my first course and we receive "guided labs" where we follow step by step instructions and copy paste bits of code to create an app. Following the instructions, I've gotten stuck at a certain spot and have tried googling/ researching to no avail.

The app is called Restaurant and essentially allows a user to look at a menu (see items/ pricing/ details) and add certain items to an order, which then shows in another tab called "Your Order". Those parts have been completed but the step I'm on is "to update the badge value of the Order tab to match the number of items in the order. Then the user can see that they've successfully added an item without needing to switch tabs." The UITabBarItem is an optional as stated in the instructions inside AppDelegate but is nil.

This line produces the error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

The error trail seems to originate in `updateOrderBadge()` specifically with adjusting the `orderTabBarItem` being the main issue. Commenting out that single line, everything runs although of course I don't get the desired badge notification. Not sure why that line which comes directly from the guide is having issues:

```
@objc func updateOrderBadge() {
        orderTabBarItem.badgeValue = String(MenuController.shared.order.menuItems.count)
    }
```

I've seen this or a similar error before when I forgot to connect IBOutlets/ Actions from button to code, is there supposed to be something like that for UITabBarItem?

For some overall context, here are the instructions and the code in screenshots:

Screenshot of specific lab instructions that I thought I followed step by step/ copy and pasted directly
[image]

A screenshot of the storyboard for context
[image]

Code inside AppDelegate that I'm altering
[image]

Otherwise here is the code in app delegate in text:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var orderTabBarItem: UITabBarItem!

    @objc func updateOrderBadge() {
        orderTabBarItem.badgeValue = String(MenuController.shared.order.menuItems.count)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        orderTabBarItem = (self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers?[1].tabBarItem

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateOrderBadge), name: MenuController.orderUpdatedNotification, object: nil)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {

        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {

    }

}
```

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Break point on the problematic line and ensure the variables are initialized correctly. Likely an issue elsewhere, although weird `orderTabBarItem` returns nil when initialized in app-delegate. Ensure that code is run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using Xcode 11 for your project, which is why you have a `SceneDelegate.swift` file in your project, and UIScene-related methods in your `AppDelegate.swift` file.

By default the template in Xcode 11 is using a `SceneDelegate` and all the related methods that came with iOS 13, so the app launch process differs a lot from the one in iOS 12.

In iOS 13, the `window` is no longer a property of the `AppDelegate`, but is instead managed by default by the `SceneDelegate`.

I think the project for the course you're following now, has been created with an earlier version of Xcode, which is why they're asking you to add a `window` property in `AppDelegate`, and initialize it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, and the problem is that this is not the correct way to do it anymore in iOS 13.

So long story short, by default the app delegate now uses the default scene configuration, and the scene delegate is responsible for setting the UIWindow object via the `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` delegate method. By default, it uses the Main.storyboard to create your first screen.

In your case to solve your problem, you would simply need to access the `window` property from the `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` delegate method of the `SceneDelegate` like so:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var orderTabBarItem: UITabBarItem!

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        orderTabBarItem = (self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers?[1].tabBarItem
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you want to make your project compatible for iOS 12 as well (and keep a window property in the AppDelegate), you could also do that, but I would not recommend.

Anyway, you can find more interesting information at the link below, which shows the difference between the old launch process, and the new launch process, and more importantly explains how you can set up the new launch process in iOS 13, whether you decide to use Storyboards or not:

https://learnappmaking.com/scene-delegate-app-delegate-xcode-11-ios-13/#using-scene-delegate-with-storyboards

Feel free to ask if you still have a doubt, and good luck for your course :)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Moving all those fragments of code into SceneDelegate has gotten it to work. I remember earlier projects also had some compatibility issues but that never occurred to me that it was the error with this!

Comment: Awesome! I guess it can be a little bit confusing for a first project indeed, because it changed very recently, and it's not always mentioned.. But anyway I'm glad you could manage to have it work! Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed a step where `window` is initialized. Try initializing the window inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Also, add the observer after the `orderTabBarItem` is set. Like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let tabBarItem = tabBarController.viewControllers?[1].tabBarItem {
            orderTabBarItem = tabBarItem
            print("Successfully set orderTabBarItem")
        } else {
            print("TabBarController didn't have any viewControllers")
        }
    } else {
        print("rootViewController isn't a UITabBarController")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateOrderBadge), name: MenuController.orderUpdatedNotification, object: nil)

    return true
}
```

Comment: It seems that regardless of those changes (adding `window = UIWindow()` to `didFinishLAunchingWithOptions` and switching the order of the two) has no effect. The app still crashes when I press the "add to order" button and the same error for `orderTabBarItem.badgeValue = String(MenuController.shared.order.menuItems.count)` still occurs.

Comment: In that case, `orderTabBarItem` initialization must be failing. Are you sure you're setting the rootViewController as UITabBarController?

Comment: Check the step I've added and see what is getting printed to your console.

Comment: Ah it looks like you were correct in your suspicion. `rootViewController isn't a UITabBarController`. If I'm being honest though, I'm not sure how to alter that. I believe rootViewController has got to be a table view controller and the only tab bar controller is the very first screen for it.

Comment: It's the other way round. Root should be a tabBarController and according to your initialisation it should at least have 2 view controllers for this to work. Why don't you go through your tutorial again and figure out what they are doing to set the initial scene of your app. If you still find it difficult maybe post another question a provide the detail and I'll try to help you out.